# Can a family pool their duty free allowances entering Australia?

Tags: australia, duty-free, family

This is a question that came up with a colleague of mine, who is returning to the UK for a visit.  If they have a family of 4 with two children under 18, can you pool your allowance for alcohol, assuming the parents buy it but use their children's allowance?

(at no point will the children be purchasing or drinking the alcohol)

Comment: You might check the wording. In Canada the children have no allowance for alchohol, so pooling wont help. You cannot even have one item which exceed the allowance for one person, so pooling is more like assigning what each family member purchased.

Comment: @Itai Yeah, that's what we were wondering for the alcohol, as they'd be carrying. I found the answer for Australia, and indeed, the kids can be assigned non-alcoholic goods, but not alcohol or cigarettes (see answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Sydney Airport's page](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/relax/syd-airport-tax-and-duty-free/duty-free-allowances):

> A family entering Australia can pool their individual allowances.
>
> For example: a family of 4 (2 adults and 2 children) are entitled to
>   bring in:
>
> 4.5 litres of alcoholic beverages (2 x adults alcohol allowance of 2.25L= 4.5L)
>
> +
>
> 100 cigarettes (2 x adults tobacco allowance of 50 cigarettes = 100)
>
> +
>
> $2,700 worth of general goods (including gifts, souvenirs, cameras,
>   electronic equipment, leather goods, jewellery, watches and sporting
>   goods) (2 x adults general goods allowance + 2 x traveller under 18
>   years general goods allowance).

(edit) So to be clearer - for alcohol and cigarettes, you cannot allocate to the kids, but you can for other items with no age limits.